# AWS Athena SQL add date_diff column based on one column and a static value

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I'm trying to run the following query:

```
select date_diff('second',timeseries.timestampminute,max(timeseries.timestampminute)),
as elapsed_sec,
timeseries.grouttake
from timeseries
```

because I want the elapsed time to be the time between the highest datetime value in the table and each row in the table but I keep getting hit with the error:

> "SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:8: '"timeseries"."grouttake"' must be an
>   aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause"

Any ideas?

Comment: I think there is an error in the query. There is comma before as elapsed_sec. Also could you provide sample rows for timeseries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `max` is an aggregate but your select operates on each row, both statements cannot be executed within the same row context.

What you need to do is calculate the max in one query and then compare with every row in a different context. This can be done within one select through joins.

```
select 
date_diff('second',
          timeseries.timestampminute,
          max_query.maxts) as elapsed_sec
from timeseries
cross join (select max(timeseries.timestampminute) maxts 
            from timeseries) 
         as max_query
```